# How to get the Headers/Column Name of gridview table binded with SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

I want to extract the columns names of gridview and bind those columns names with a drop down to make a filter template. I'm facing little challenge to get the columns names from gridview on page load event. Below is the code what i am trying with error.

and "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index"

```
Response.Write(GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text.ToString());
Response.Write(GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text.ToString());
Response.Write(GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[2].Text.ToString());
Response.Write(GridView1.Rows[0].Cells[3].Text.ToString());
```

Above code is not working, if it works i can add this in foreach loop for each column

Note : There is some hidden (visible=false) fields also in gridview

Comment: Are you binding the DGV to a DataTable?

Comment: It's asp.net grid view:   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"

Comment: But what is the source of data?

Comment: <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" DataSourceMode="DataSet"
                        runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString1 %>"
                        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnectionString1.ProviderName %>"
                        SelectCommand="

Comment: You can get the column header names (column name) from the DataTable in the DataSet. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.columnname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Emmad, That's not working in my case. Can you please suggest the working code? with SqlDataSource and Gridview

Answer (score 0):

You can get column names in 2 ways (at least):

1-Using the datagrid itself:

```
            //assuming you have a dataset with 1 datatable
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            this.GridView1.DataSource=ds;
            DataBind();
            //after binding is complete
            this.headerNames.Text="";

            foreach (var c in GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells)
            {
                this.headerNames.Text += (((System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell)(c)).ContainingField).HeaderText+",";
            }
```

2-Using the binding source (in your case a datatable)

```
        //After you load the datatable from the data source
        this.headerNames.Text = "";
        foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
        {
            this.headerNames.Text += dc.ColumnName+",";
        }
```